# How to prevent line from getting run in build.gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I currently have a gradle application and am using the gradle-docker plugin.

I have in my build.gradle file two Docker tasks, each that is supposed to tag an image for the appropriate Container Registry (specified by project.group) :

```
task buildDockerSandbox(type: Docker) {
    project.group = 'gcr.io/sandbox'
    baseImage "java:8"
    runCommand("mkdir a")
    addFile("a.jar", "a/")
    workingDir("/a")
    entryPoint(["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=sandbox", "-jar", "a.jar"])
}

task buildDockerProd(type: Docker) {
    project.group = 'gcr.io/prod'
    baseImage "java:8"
    runCommand("mkdir b")
    addFile("b.jar", "b/")
    workingDir("/b")
    entryPoint(["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar", "b.jar"])
}
```

However, when I run "gradle buildDockerSandbox", the line "project.group = 'gcr.io/prod'" gets registered while the buildDockerSandbox task is running, causing the image to be tagged for the wrong environment.

I need to disable the task not is NOT being ran from actually running the "project.group = {group}" line in order to prevent this, but don't know how.

**Expected result:** Running "gradle buildDockerSandbox" tags an image as "gcr.io/sandbox:{applicationName}" and running "gradle buildDockerProd" tags an image as "gcr.io/prod:{applicationName}".

**Actual result:** Both tasks are tagging an image as "gcr.io/prod:{applicationName}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stuff you add in the closure for the task is applied when Gradle is configuring your tasks - not when actually running them. So in this case, you are defining two tasks, and both of them sets a shared property `project.group`. So whatever task happens to be configured last "wins", no matter which one you actually intend to run.

There are many Docker plugins for Gradle available, and it looks to me like you use the one from [Transmode](https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker). From the documentation, it appears you can't build two images with different Docker repository names in the same Gradle project. So I would say your options are to either set the name yourself after the image is built (e.g. in a doLast block), split it into two Gradle projects, or use another Docker plugin that is more customizable. The one from [bmuschko](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) is probably the most widely used and feature rich.